# setOnClickListener error - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I want to create a button which, when clicked, it will show another intent.

This is the code:

```
   <Button
    android:text="Bine ati venit!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="#479fc7"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:onClick="next_page"/>
```

and from the .java class:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
}

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick (View v){
    next_page(v);
}
});

public void next_page(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I get the errors:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'", "variable onClick is never used", "; expected"....

Comment: Why are you not putting your `button` inside the `onCreate` method?

Comment: You already set in your xml file the tag android:onClick="next_page", so you can delete your Button init and it's onClickListener

Comment: oh, I didn't see that... thx!

Comment: Compilation error from a typo. Voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

// You must move the code you type into the class method and work like the following

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Find the View that shows the numbers category
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

// Set a click listener on that View
        numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // The code in this method will be executed when the numbers View is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumberActivity.class);
                startActivity(numbersIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put that particular snippet inside `OnCreate()`. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code like this

```
Button button;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome); 
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){ 
        public void onClick (View v){ 
            next_page(v); 
        } 
    }); 

} 

public void next_page(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and you don't need to pass View object to `next_page()` if you don't use it there

Answer (score 0):

You either declare onClick attribute with method name in your xml or programaticaly set it in onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (View v){
           next_page(v);
        }
    });
}

public void next_page(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the error:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'"
It might be worth making sure that you have imported TextView by adding

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the location of the code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick (View v){
     next_page(v);
     }
 });
}
```

> Cut the Code and paste it in the OnCreate method. As it doesn't make sense to **set** the **OnClickListener** after the button is created. That's why the error occured.